# Drop the rows which contains duplicate values in 2 columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which looks like this.

```
        A   B
    0   cat fish
    1   dog dog
    2   cat fish
    3   dog cat
```

I want to drop the rows which contain a duplicate value in both columns.
The resulting data frame should only have.

```
        A   B
    0   cat fish
    2   cat fish
    3   dog cat
```

I've tried using 
`df.drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'])`

But it gives me the following dataframe.

```
        A    B
    0   cat fish
    1   dog dog
    3   dog cat
```

any suggestion on how can I get my expected output?

Comment: thumbs up for including a great minimal example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`df.nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) on `axis=1` and filter out rows which return 1:

```
df[~df.nunique(1).eq(1)]
```

---

```
     A     B
0  cat  fish
2  cat  fish
3  dog   cat
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
res = df[df['A']!=df['B']]
```